# Selected a Filtered range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list Object that I filter by date. Once I have a filtered array. I would like to set a range on `Column D` to have a For loop that read the filtered range

Here is my code

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Invoices").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & Year.value
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Invoices").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=" & Month.value

Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Invoices").Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0)
MsgBox r.Address
```

`Column D` have a Header in  `D1`.  When I filter my range should be `D75:D90` ... but the msgbox returns `D2:D90` like if the Data were not filtered.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just use *SpecialCells property* like below:

```
Dim r As Range, c As Range

With Sheets("Invoices").Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown))
    Set r = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
'~~> Use Areas property if you want to loop
'~~> through the filtered data as posted by lukas2
For Each c In r.Areas
    Msgbox c.Address
Next
```

Also you need to resize your range to explicitly work on cells with values.
That is to compensate your offset to exclude the headers.

Answer (score 0):

to check filtered items you have to loop over areas, eg:

```
Dim Filtered As Range
Dim a As Variant
Dim g As Variant

Set Filtered = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each a In Filtered.Areas
    For Each g In a.Rows
        MsgBox g.Address
    Next g
Next a
```